# Drupal Bulk Update Nodes using button

Tags: nodes, views

I have view that displays a table of node for the current user.

I am confused as to how i can provide the functionality to bulk update certain values.

For example:

I have table of nodes (custom content type=List) and that content type has a custom field called list_status.

I want to update the value of the list_status for all the selected nodes.

I looked at VBO (Views Bulk Operation) to do this, i managed to do it with "Modify Entity Value" setting but the UI/UX i get with this is not what i desire. It takes me to a new page to select the value.

What i need to do is is run this action on a button click. I would really appreciate if some one can please help me figure this out?

I felt, i would only be able to accomplish this by doing something custom with my own module but if i am right, then a starting point for this would also be just as much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have solved my issue, i will try to elaborate for future reference and also for any one who may need this.

First, it seems i missed the "Bulk operations settings" section as it was collapsed by default. But one of the options under it is "Display operations as" which provides two choices (1) Dropdown selectbox with Submit button and (2) Each action as a separate button

The second option was what i needed to get the buttons i wanted.

Then for bulk updating a custom field of my content type, i added **hook_action_info()** into my custom module and created a custom action that would become visible where the "Modify Entity Value" option was.